# If $Ker(T^r)=Ker(T^{r+n})$ does that imply $Im(T^r)=Im(T^{r+n})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Here T is a linear transformation and an n dimensional vector space V, $T:V\rightarrow V$. And $r$ is such that $Ker(T^r)=Ker(T^{r+j})\ \forall j\geq1$

Also, how can I show that $W=T^r(V)$ is T- invariant?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: dimension formula (or whatever else name you know for the fact that $\dim\left(\operatorname*{Ker} f\right) + \dim\left(\operatorname*{Im} f\right) = \dim V$ for any linear map $f: V \to W$).

Answer (score 1):

You have always $\mathrm{ker}T^{r} \subset \mathrm{ker}T^{r+j}$, since if $T^{r}v=0$, then $T^{r+j}v= T^{j}\left(T^{r}v\right)=T^{j}0=0$. Similarly, you have $\mathrm{im}T^{r+j} \subset \mathrm{im}T^{r}$, since $T^{r+j}v=T^{r}\left(T^{j}v\right)$. Since for a generic endomorphism $F$ you have that the sums of the dimension of ker and im are equal to n, if $\mathrm{ker}T^{r}=\mathrm{ker}T^{r+j}$ then the dimensions of $\mathrm{im}T^{r}$ and of $\mathrm{im}T^{r+j}$ are equal. But $\mathrm{im}T^{r+j} \subset \mathrm{im}T^{r}$, so they must coincide.

Now we are done also for the second question, since $T\left(T^{r}V\right)=\mathrm{im}T^{r+1} = \mathrm{im}T^{r}= T^{r} V$.